# how to encode a UInt32 scalar type into a NSData object

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdata, uint32

I am currently creating this NSData object. I would like to put in sever different objects that are of type NSString and UInt32. I know how to put a NSString into my NSData object, but I don't know how to do this with a UInt32 scalar type.

this is how I do it with a NSString

```
- (void) constructRequest
{
    NSString *mystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[self addMethodName]];
    UInt32 protocolInt = [self addProtocolVersion];

    NSData* data=[mystring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:@"/Users/imac/Desktop/_dataDump.dat" atomically:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 4):

So I have figured it out, and instead of just updating my question I will put in the answer so others can see that this question has been answered if they are looking to do something similar.

code is as follows

```
- (void) constructRequest
{
    //NSString *mystring = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[self addMethodName]];
    UInt32 protocolInt = [self addProt];

    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:&protocolInt length:sizeof(protocolInt)];

    //NSData* data=[mystring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:@"/Users/imac/Desktop/_dataDump.dat" atomically:YES];

}
```

Comment: Don't do that. It's not endian-safe (PowerPC Macs and Intel Macs will read it differently.)

Comment: hrmm. So how to I make it endian-safe? currently I am trying to make it big-endian, I have outputted the result to a .dat folder on my desktop and opened that with HexEdit to check the results, and its currently reading it as big-endian.. any suggestions on how I can make this safe.

Comment: Byte-swap it to a known order first using `CFSwapInt32HostToBig()` or `CFSwapInt32HostToLittle()`. When reading it in, swap the resulting integer back to native order with `CFSwapInt32BigToHost()` or `CFSwapInt32LittleToHost()` as appropriate.

Comment: okay cool, thanks for the heads up. I'm going to have to give this more investigation.. Although I know what your talking about I have only ever heard of this while doing some c++

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be NSData? You could use NSString or NSNumber (both can be saved in a property list).

Your scheme doesn't really distinguish between a 4-byte string and a UInt32, if that matters.

Comment: I am planning on adding a leading Uint16 number to the start of each property so when it makes it to the server the server can deal with each section in the reciver class. Is that what you were referring to? The only issue being is that I am not sure on how to create one NSData structure out of several... im investigating that currently.

Comment: NSData is just data. But what you said you wanted to do was save different objects. Instead of focusing on NSData, just save the objects (NSString and NSNumber), as keyed values in a property list (NSDictionary).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `htonl()`,`htons()`, `ntohl()` and `ntohs()` to make it endian-safe.

```
 htonl()--"Host to Network Long int"     32Bytes
 ntohl()--"Network to Host Long int"     32Bytes
 htons()--"Host to Network Short int"   16Bytes
 ntohs()--"Network to Host Short int"   16Bytes
```

Example:

```
- (void)testExample {

UInt32 length = 0x1a2b3c4d;
NSLog(@"%x", length);
length = htonl(length);
NSLog(@"%x", length);
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[data appendBytes:&length length:4];
NSLog(@"%@", data);

}
```

print:

```
2015-10-29 15:46:49.224 UPHTTP-iOS[3896:101301] 1a2b3c4d
2015-10-29 15:46:49.224 UPHTTP-iOS[3896:101301] 4d3c2b1a
2015-10-29 15:46:49.224 UPHTTP-iOS[3896:101301] <1a2b3c4d>
```